# Windows 7 brightness slider suddenly gone

Tags: windows-7, display, vga, brightness

Brightness slider in power plan settings recently disappeared.

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: when you Click "More power options" can you see the slider on the bottom ? can you adjust the brightness from another place ? does the keyboard-shortcut to dimm the screen sill works ? please provide more details

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is:

Start -> Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Device Manager.

In the Device Manager window, look for “Monitors”, then right-click your monitor and select “Uninstall”. Be sure to also check the “Remove driver” option. Once removed, click the “Scan for hardware changes” icon.

Voila. “Adjust plan brightness” returns, mystery solved.

*References:*
[Wayne Khan's Blog](http://kzhiwei.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-laptop-screen-brightness-slider-windows-7/)
[Microsoft TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/08a3eb1d-b698-4639-af4b-5278b721fcdc/)

Comment: Anyone knows **WHY THIS ACTUALLY HAPPENS?** :D