# Screen brightness slider disappeared on Windows 7. How do I bring it back?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, brightness

So I can't find the screen brightness slider or any brightness adjustment option in my power plan options. All I can do is determine when to put the laptop to sleep and when to turn off the display.

It seems like the common solution for many was to go to Device Manager and uninstall the driver under Monitors, then scan for hardware changes. I did that and it didn't work. If it helps, under my Monitors section it says "Generic PnP Monitor".

Update: I've since found a semi-solution. I can adjust the brightness by holding the Fn key and pressing up/down on my arrow keys. However, the brightness sliders are still missing.

Comment: What kind of monitor / Video Card?  Is this an OEM Utility like from HP or Lenovo?  That maybe the issue..

Comment: Not so familiar with this stuff. What do you mean by the kind of monitor? The laptop I'm using is a Dell Studio XPS.

Comment: Did you install Windows yourself or did it come on the laptop?  An OEM (Original Equipment Manufacturer) like Dell does have the ability to distribute Windows as part of a package with systems they sell.

Comment: The laptop was a gift so I don't know what it started with, but there's a sticker that shows Windows Vista on it, so I'm gonna assume Windows did come with the laptop and Windows 7 was later installed on it.

Comment: See the response..  Is that the slider you refer to?  If you go to a customized power plan, you may see some odd things..  What about going to default power plan?

Comment: That's the one, but it's missing. It looks like this (this is the Balanced plan, which is default): http://i.imgur.com/QuAXlk2.png

Comment: go here please - http://superuser.com/questions/308721/windows-7-brightness-slider-suddenly-gone

Comment: I already tried that as shown in the description..

Answer (score 2):

If it is a laptop, it will most likely come back if you reinstall manufacturer's management tools software. The are usually full of unwanted stuff, but if you uninstall them, those on screen goodies like screen brightness indicator will go away too.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem and I just found out a really easy and fast way to find the slider. It wont even take a minute.

Just go to control panel, then hardware and sound, then power options. In the power options window, wether you use the balanced or power saver plan, you will find a "change plan settings" button.

Press that, then below the display adjustments, press the "change advanced power settings". A little box will appear, and you will find a "change settings that are currently unavailable" button. Press that, and then scroll down until you find display. Click on the plus sign on the left side of it, then click the plus sign of the "Display Brightness". From there you can adjust it to your liking. 
               Hope that helps. 
Best of luck to all of you,
Contributer

Comment: I did what you said, and even that option is missing! http://i.imgur.com/soRemk8.png

Anyway, I've since found a way to adjust the brightness. I can just hold the Fn key and press up and down on my arrow keys. But all traces of the brightness slider are still gone.

Answer (score 0):

I have a windows 10 laptop more than 5 years old. I have been with full brightness for a month or so on the laptop panel. The brightness control disappeared from everywhere (Activity panel, power plan options, screen configuration...) after an S.O. update. I didn't mind too much because I work at a very well lit room and brightness was almost full anyway. What bothers me is that the "night display" function stopped working on the laptop panel, but was still working on the addition monitor, so after dark I work with two monitors at different brightness levels.

The way to restore the brightness control was through the Device Manager. There I saw both monitors (Generic PnP monitor) as "disabled". I enabled both of them and the brightness control reappeared in all the right places.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind - I see the slider you talk about..

Here - [image: Slider]

It is in the Power Plan information.

I am sure it is in Control Panel too.

Comment: That would be screen resolution, hes after brightness. Its likely under power settings.

Comment: Yep..  I realized that right as soon as I was posting it.  Updated to show the brightness sliders he is talking about.

Comment: My problem is that it's mysteriously not there. Mine looks like that but without anything related to brightness. http://i.imgur.com/QuAXlk2.png

Comment: Do you know when this disappeared?  Like 1 or 2 days ago?  What about restoring your system to that point?

Comment: go here please - http://superuser.com/questions/308721/windows-7-brightness-slider-suddenly-gone